# How to use a Generic Parameter in Web Api Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to have one API Endpoint that allow me to perform multiple operations with a generic input. for instance, i want to delete an employee either by ID or BY name. Just by changing parameter.

what i have tried is using the OR operator (||):

```
  public int DeleteBusinessStream(int id, string name)
    {
        var deleteBusinessStream = this.dbcontext.BusinessStreams.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BusinessStreamId == id || p.BusinessStreamName == name);

        if(deleteBusinessStream == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.dbcontext.BusinessStreams.Remove(deleteBusinessStream);
            this.dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Controller

```
  [HttpDelete]
    [Route("deletebusinessstream")]
    public ActionResult deleteBusinessStream(int id, string name)
    {
        PostMessage pm = new PostMessage();

        int returnedValue = this.jobsApi.DeleteBusinessStream(id, name);

        if(returnedValue == 1)
        {
            pm.error = true;
            pm.message = "Delete Business Stream was not successful!!";
        }
        else
        {
            pm.error = false;
            pm.message = "Delete Business Stream was successful";
            var deleteStream = this.jobsApi.DeleteBusinessStream(id, name);
        }

        return Ok(pm);


    }
```

This works well but it requires input two parameter values ( id and name ) i want to be able to use one to switch and perform delete based on any one i choose like

```
 https://localhost:7190/api/Employer/deletebusinessstream?id=111
```

or

```
 https://localhost:7190/api/Employer/deletebusinessstream?name=ICT
```

instead of passing both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can make both parameters optional like this in your Web API Action

```
public ActionResult deleteBusinessStream(int id = 0, string name = null)
```

And later check in code if the id is 0, then use the name to delete and vice-versa i.e if the name is null use id to delete the records

***Also, you cannot restrict user from passing both parameters in the request so you need to handle that request separately and return BadRequest maybe***

This way you can call your endpoint with either of the URLs

```
https://localhost:7190/api/Employer/deletebusinessstream?id=111

https://localhost:7190/api/Employer/deletebusinessstream?name=ICT
```

**Although I would say that Name will not be a unique identifier for a record, so I suggest you take a dig and check whether you actually want to delete the record using the name**